# Navigate to the Private DNS Mode Page using Android Intent

Tags: java, android, settings

[image: example]

I want to navigate to this dns page. Does anyone have any resources for listing the intent navigation string once I've navigated to a specific settings page?

Comment: Did you figure this out?  I want to do the same thing.